# Add maven project build to tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I used to add my maven project to tomcat server v7.0 by right click server -> add and remove -> select my project -> Finish.

But today i dont find my maven project in the list.
There is only one project in the Available section.
How can i have my project in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this kind of junk in IRAD (the IBM version of Eclipse) many times.  I think the software is just plain buggy.  Make sure you back up your code somewhere else, like in your code repository, and delete all your projects including local files.  Then check everything out again.  Also, tomcat is great for picking up changes in its webapps folder.  You might want to just forget about deploying through eclipse all together.  You have some other options that will actually allow you to see changes immediately with out having to redeploy.

```
Hot deploy solutions
1) Use Jrebel - this is expense
2) Expand your war in the webapps folder and send symbolic links back to     your target folders containing your class, and to you jsp, javascript directories
3) Expand your war in the webapps folder and use filesync plug in (its been hard to find on the web for a while) to copy your changes to the expanded area
```

Other ways just to send your war/ear over, not hot deploy

```
1) Change your maven code to copy the ear/war to the tomcat directory for you every time you run maven install
```

Fully integrated IDE to webserver seems to be fantasy that they never quite worked out as far as I can tell.